# Qt cannot load MySql driver on XAMPP

Tags: c++, qt, xampp, qt5

I have written a very simple test to see how database connection works. This is my first attempt :

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
 db.setHostName("localhost");
 db.setPort(3306);
 db.setDatabaseName("testqt");
 db.setUserName("aaaaaa");
 db.setPassword(".bbbbbb!,");

 if (db.open())
 {
     qDebug() << "Connected!";          
 }else
 {
     qDebug() << "Failed to connect!";
 }
```

Why I always get this `error`?

[image]

---

Note that I have this :

[image]

I have also seen online that someone puts the `libmysql.dll` and I've done that but still nothing. I have installed the *C* and *C++* `mysql` connector from internet. Any idea?

My SQL database is on a *XAMPP* server and this is the username :

[image]

Also note this:

[image]

There is mariadb but it asks for `libmysql`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have using of *MinGW* compiler, download c connector from bellow link :

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Then copy  `"libmysql.dll"` dll file to your qt path where installed :

```
C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin
```